# Trying to convert a javascript object to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a decoded Json variable called `objIntChart` that looks like the following when I console.log() it.

[image: objIntChart]

The problem is I need it as an array that looks like this

[image]

I did a foreach loop like this in an attempt to solve it:

```
   var array = [];

            objIntChart.forEach(function (entry) {
                var x = 0++;
                array.push(x);
                array.x.push(entry['dateTime']);
                array.x.push(entry['entries']);

            });
```

However the problem is that I cannot do a push on array.x because it takes the x as the name and not the variable. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
var array = [];
objIntChart.forEach(function (entry) {
    array.push([entry['dateTime'], entry['entries']]);
});
```

Comment: For the record, with your approach you'd have needed `array[x] = []`, `array[x].push(..)`.

Comment: Doh I am stupid. I actually did something along the lines of that first but then I just went completely off track. Anyways thanks for the response

Answer (score 1):

This will do as well:

```
var arr = objIntChart.map(function (obj) { return [obj.dateTimes, obj.entries]});
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `array[x]` instead of `array.x` and also be doing `array[x] = []` or `array.push([])` instead of `array.push(x)` which will add the integer `x`, not an empty array, to your array.

Also, you will need to set `var x = 0;` outside your forloop and do `x++` inside it. Currently, `x` will always be `1` when you use it.